# What's the difference between CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().SizeChanged & Window.Current.SizeChanged event

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

In Windows Store app, we need an event which is occurred when the device orientation is changed. I've found two events, anybody knows what's the difference in between them?

[Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.sizechanged%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

[Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.sizechanged%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Nice question. I would also like an explained answer :-)

Comment: and maybe same events. Just overriden :-) That's a guess from common understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.aspx)  :

> A Window object is just surfacing information from CoreWindow, which
> in turn is referencing the window created by the system.

`CoreWindow` is just an object that provides input events for `Window` so the two events are referencing the same system event.

Comment: So which one should be used & why?

Comment: `CoreWindow` is not a low-level `Window`, for example it doesn't have `Content` property, it's just the object that provides input events for `Window` and there are some events that are only available through this object, like `CharacterReceived`, `AcceleratorKeyActivated` etc.